# Python Networkx MultiDiGraph paths

Tags: python, networkx

Is there a function that, given a node and a MultiDiGraph, returns all of the possible paths from this node? I'm fairly certain I could implement it myself, but if it's already built into the library, I would prefer to use that.

Comment: What kind of paths do you want?  Shortest, or simple?  Is your graph acyclic?

Comment: Since it's directed, it has some finite number of unique paths from any given node. I'd like a list of all these paths. Specifically, I want to see if two paths that start at the same node re-merge at the same node (so that I can merge the paths into a consensus path).

Comment: By unique do you mean not repeating nodes?  In that case maybe networkx.all_simple_paths() will work?

Comment: Will this work if I don't specify a target?

Comment: No, you need to specify a target but you can just make a loop and specify all other nodes as targets right?

Comment: Thank you so much for your continued help!